# Django. Custom tag

Tags: django

I would like to display all of elements from object in a custom tag

```
@register.simple_tag
def user_wszyscy1(lang=None):
    sale = Sala.objects.all()
    if lang:
        sale = sale.filter(wybrany_jezyk=lang)
    return sale
```

How to display all elements in a template file?

I tried with for loop:

```
Sale to:
{% for user_wszyscy1 in user_wszyscy1 %}

{{sale}}

{%endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an [assignment tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags), not a simple tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should better create tag like this

```
@register.simple_tag
def user_wszyscy1(sale, lang):
    if lang:
        sale = sale.filter(wybrany_jezyk=lang)
    return sale
```

and use it like this:

```
Sale to:
{% for sala in sale|user_wszyscy1:"pl" %}

{{sale}}

{% endfor %}
```

`sale` should be in your context already, it's not good to retrieve data from your models in template tags, it should be done in views on in context_processors.